# Encriptar y Desencriptar paquetes en Python

Tags: c#, python, socket

estoy realizando un programa cliente de chat en Python basándome en uno hecho en C#, la cuestión es que los mensajes que recibo del servidor están cifrados y no se como obtener el mismo método de desencriptar en C# en python, adjunto el código.
Para lo que es el key y el IV ya lo tengo resuelto.

C#

```
public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] data)
{
    byte[] result;
 
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(data))
    using (AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider())
    using (ICryptoTransform enc = aes.CreateDecryptor(this.Key, this.IV))
    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, enc, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
    {
        result = new byte[data.Length];
        int size = cs.Read(result, 0, result.Length);
        result = result.Take(size).ToArray();
    }
 
    return result;
}
```

Lo que tengo en Pytho hasta ahora

```
def Decrypt(self,data):
    self.cipher = AES.new(self.Key, AES.MODE_CFB,self.IV)
    self.original_data = self.cipher.decrypt(data)
    return self.original_data
```

Comment: Te refieres a traducir el método a py?

Comment: @FabioPalm mmm si algo así

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

```
#   pip install pycrypto
#   or 
#   pip install pycryptodome


from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import os


def pad(s):
    return s + b"\0" * (AES.block_size - len(s) % AES.block_size)

# rellenamos con * para que la contrasena pueda tener 32 bytes
# en caso de ser menor a los 32 bytes
# y determinamos el typo de la data

def typeKey(data):
    if(type(data) is str):
        data = bytes(("*"*(32-len(data)) + data).encode("utf-8"))
    
    if(type(data) is bytes):
        data = b"*"*(32-len(data)) + data
    
    return data

def typeData(data):

    if(type(data) is str):
        data = bytes(data.encode("utf-8"))
    
    return data

def encrypt(message, key, key_size=256):
    key = typeKey(key)
    message = pad(typeData(message))
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    return iv + cipher.encrypt(message)

def decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    # rellenamos con * para que la contrasena pueda tener 32 bytes
    key = typeKey(key)
    ciphertext = typeData(ciphertext)
    iv = ciphertext[:AES.block_size]
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    plaintext = cipher.decrypt(ciphertext[AES.block_size:])

    return plaintext.rstrip(b"\0")


def encrypt_file(file_name,key):
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
            plaintext = fo.read()
        enc = encrypt(plaintext, key)
        with open(file_name + ".enc", 'wb') as fo:
            fo.write(enc)
        os.remove(file_name)
        return file_name + ".enc"
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

def decrypt_file(file_name,key):
    try:
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as fo:
            ciphertext = fo.read()
        dec = decrypt(ciphertext, key)
        with open(file_name[:-4], 'wb') as fo:
            fo.write(dec)
        os.remove(file_name)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

texto ="hola como estas?"
key = "ErSP8I89EZ40uPVUWPSctHMBvzUffKZu"
#key = "contra"
#key = bytes(("*"*(32-len(key)) + key).encode("utf-8"))

# encryp file
fn ="documento.txt"

# retorna el nombre del archivo
nfn = encrypt_file(fn,key)

# desencrypta el archivo
decrypt_file(nfn,key)


# encrypt texto
cryp = encrypt(texto,key)
print(cryp)

# desencrypta el texto
deco = decrypt(cryp,key).decode("utf-8")
print(deco)
```

Comment: lo probaré, luego comento como me fue